# I don't know how to transfer files in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, go

When I select a picture in flutter, I get this data, I want to send this data to the golang server, but I don't know how. I am using http package without using dio.

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EE757681-C1B8-4FCC-BAB2-9A685A29E4A5/tmp/image_picker_06D171DF-30FA-4C15-908E-7FE4AD379DD9-23404-000012F0F6E55F99.png
```

I don't even know how to get a file from golang and save it to s3, but first I want to be able to transfer it from flutter to golang.

How can I control the image on the golang server? Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use **MultipartRequest class** to that purpose as it say in http package documentation

```
var uri = Uri.https('example.com', 'create');
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
  ..fields['user'] = 'nweiz@google.com'
  ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'package', 'build/package.tar.gz',
      contentType: MediaType('application', 'x-tar')));
var response = await request.send();
if (response.statusCode == 200) print('Uploaded!');
```

[MultipartRequest class](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html)